# Menu outside container / Background image vertical stretch

Tags: image, menu, background, alignment, stretch

I've been trying to fix this most of the weekend, but I can't seem to get it right, the basics of my website are complete, but for 2 things:

- The ul.nav fits all of the buttons, however, a 10-15 pixel area is sticking out to the left. out of the ul.nav. (i'm using MS expression web 4, it's marked by diagonal red lines. It prevents the menu to align correctly, and worse, it causes one menu button to drop below the others when viewing the site in 1024*768. :-(
- The background picture for the container div (called "Div" in the code) does not stretch vertically, but repeats itself. It creates annoying lines that way. Is there a way to make it stretch?

Many thanks for your advice. The code is included below.

The HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="masthead" class="masthead" 
onclick="window.location.href='Index.html'"; style="cursor:pointer"></div>
<div id="top-nav" >     
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#"> Europe </a></li>
            <li><a href="ContentNA.html"> N. America </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> S. America </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Asia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Africa </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Australia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Misc </a></li></ul>
            </div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="message">
<br clear="all" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The CSS

```
body {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: center center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
body: ;
background-image: url('BG_MP.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
div {
border-radius: 15px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: none;
width: 70%;
margin: 50px auto 10px auto;
padding: 10px;
background-image: url('parchment.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
left: auto;
right: auto;
}
#masthead {
border-radius: 15px;
background: transparent;
height: 220px;
width: 650px;
background-image: url('masthead.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#top-nav {
height: 71px;
background : transparent;
list-style : none;
margin-top : 7px;
margin-bottom : 11px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
}
ul.nav {
border-radius: 15px;
background : transparent;
height : 57px;
line-height : 31px;
list-style : none;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight: bolder;
display: inline-block
}
ul.nav li {
display : inline;
padding : 0;
background : transparent;
}
ul.nav a {
font: 100%;
background: transparent;
height : 30px;
font-size : 12px;
color: #000000;
float : left;
padding: 11px 8px 11px 8px;
text-decoration : none;
border-top: 1px solid #252525;
border-bottom : 4px solid #252525;
border-left : 1px solid transparent;
border-right : 1px solid transparent;
border-radius : 4px;
-moz-border-radius : 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
background : #252525;
border-top : 1px solid #252525;
border-bottom : 4px solid #000;
border-left : 1px solid #252525;
border-right : 1px solid #252525;
color : #FFF;
padding : 11px 8px 11px 8px;
border-radius : 4px;
-moz-border-radius : 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
#message {
background: transparent;
left: auto;
right: auto;
text-align: center
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the extra 10-15px spacing issue, add `padding:0;` to `ul.nav`

As for the repeating background of div, add the two lines that you used to do the same thing in body to it: add `background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed;` to `div`'s CSS

[jsFiddle with the implemented changes](http://jsfiddle.net/hWWLU/)

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but unfortunately it's not working. I remains to have some sort of padding. I just tried adjusting padding everywhere, but it won't fix it.

Comment: Using the exact code you provided adding only `padding:0;` to `ul.nav` does take away the extra spacing [as seen in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ryaa/). If there is still spacing in your project then it's due to some other code you have not provided

Comment: I copy / pasted the jsfiddle code and now it works. Don't know how, but I'm happy. :-) Thanks Zeaklous.